# In Android Webview before loading web page how to modify the page source?

Tags: android, webview

Am new to Android. I am doing android app in that i was loading existing web pages into my App using Webview.I did successfully for loading the web pages using Webview.But i need to delete some part of web page content before loading into web view.

Please help me with some sample codes.

### Mycode

```
private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    }

    WebView webview;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);        
        webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web);                   
        webview.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());          
        webview.loadUrl("http://stackoverflow.com"); 

        }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that with the help of javascript:

```
webview1.loadUrl("javascript:window.document.getElementsByClassName('elementToHide')[0].style.display='none';")
```

(for example)

Comment: HI Stephane.Thanks for your answer.I have a doubt where i need to add the above code.Because i already using loadurl method for loading URL.I wonder how to bind the above javascript code into that.I updated  the code in my question.Please take a look and tell me.Thanks.

Comment: @user3807045 I usually add it the public void onPageFinished. You can add a lot of these lines, in order to hide several elements. You also can change font size, and a lot of other things.

Comment: Thanks Stephane.Now got a solution.Thanks for your help.